Finding associated private key for a SSL/TLS certificate using powershell
When importing a new certificate (.pfx with password) on a windows server (2022) with .net framework 4.8 using Powershell from a remote device, the problem of addings users that can manage the private key of the certificate arises.
Is there anyway of finding the private key or the physical location of this private key via powershell and related properties of the certificate? Or a possible workaround by adding users to the managing entities of all private keys associated with the certificate?
When using the UI on the destination windows server it is possible to add users/groups to manage the private keys ex. :
UI example of user management
When trying to replicate the same action using powershell scripts
$acl = Get-Acl $keyFile.FullName

            $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($adServiceAccount, "Read", "Allow")

            $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)

            Set-Acl -Path $keyFile.FullName -AclObject $acl

the private key becomes necessary to use ACL for adding a new rule (with a new user)
But here the problem manifests of the unfindeable private key of this certificate.
Properties prove the certificate has a key:
enter image description here
Obtained via
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | *'thumbprint filter...'*
$cert.HasPrivateKey (<-- property returns true so proves a key does exist)
$privateKey = $cert.PrivateKey (<-- all properties return empty values)


Private keys are stored in a user specific certificate store which is encrypted by the user password. Access or management of cert entries and private keys by other users is to my knowledge not intended in Windows.
